# All emails for a subdomain routed to one mailbox in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a functioning Exchange 2007 system that receives mail for users@domain.com.  I'd like to set up a mailbox that will get all mail from whateveruser@subdomain.domain.com.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking for how to route all mail destined for a subdomain to a single mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Create a catchall address for subdomain.domain.com
[How to create a "catchall" mailbox sink for Exchange Server](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324021)

Comment: Sorry this is for exchange 2003

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Catchall Agent](http://www.codeplex.com/catchallagent) from Codeplex will suit your needs just fine.